# Correct way to use SQL Intersect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to build a query for the following scenario:

I have two tables *Table1* and *Table2*.

The primary keys of *Table1* goes like *T1Attr1*, *T1Attr2* and so on.

Corresponding to each primary key in *Table1*, I can get a set of attributes from *Table2* which goes like *T2Attr1*, *T2Attr2* and so on.

I'm trying to query for the attributes which are common to the attributes of *Table1*, for example, if the input is *T1Attr1* and *T1Attr2*, the results should have the attributes common to both of them from *Table2*. As the input parameters grows, the results would be less since common-to-all attributes would be less.

My query is similar to this:

```
Select indId, indName from indData where pId =1

intersect
Select indId, indName from indData where pId =2

intersect
Select indId, indName from indData where pId =3
```

The query works fine but when the pId list is huge(above 100), jdbc driver throws an error message.

Can someone please provide suggestions on using this query correctly or provide a better approach for the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the primary key of this table? And what error message do you get exactly?

Comment: Primary key is an incremented value and not included in the query. The error I get is pasted here-> http://pastebin.com/VsG92F2n

Comment: No other unique constraints on the table?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did this error was produced with the intersection of 100 tables?

Comment: No other unique constraints, and yes I got that error when when the pId was from 1 to 100(so 100 intersections)

Comment: It would be interesting if you posted a question at [DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), including the table definition, indexes and table sizes (and the error you got.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Intersect` is not the only way to do what you want.  Your query is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  The "set" is the `indid, indname` pair.  The "within-sets" are having all three values for `pid`.

I advocate using aggregation with a `having` clause for this type of query, because this is a very flexible approach for many types of conditions.  In your case, the results query is:

```
select indid, indname
from indData
group by indid, indname
having SUM(case when pid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       SUM(case when pid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       SUM(case when pid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you have an index on `pid` and the values are relatively rare, than adding a `where pid in (1, 2, 3)` could benefit the query performance-wise.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this query but it won't be as efficient as the one you have:

```
SELECT indId, indName 
FROM indData 
WHERE pId IN (1, 2, 3, ..., 100)
GROUP BY indId, indName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pId) = 100 ;  -- the number of pId you are searching on
```

---

You can also use `JOINs`. Perhaps this will result in a better execution plan and not cause this error. If there is a unique constraint on `(indId, pId)` this will be equivalent to your query:

```
SELECT a1.indId, a1.indName 
FROM indData AS a1
  JOIN indData AS a2
    ON a2.indId = a1.indId
  JOIN indData AS a3
    ON a3.indId = a1.indId 
  ...
  JOIN indData AS a100
    ON a100.indId = a1.indId
WHERE a1.pId = 1
  AND a2.pId = 2
  ...
  AND a100.pId = 100 ;
```

An index on `(pId, indID) INCLUDE (indName)` would help efficiency.